# Inverter not showing the right output in HSPICE

Tags: simulation, spice, inverter, output

This is the code snippet apart from the usual headers in the rest of the file:

```
.param VDD=0.88
.param VSS=0
.param out_capa_load = 0.1f
.param inputv=VDD

XINV in VDD VNW VPW VSS out  INV_X1B_A9TL_C35
Cload out VSS out_capa_load
vin in 0 VDD
*.ic V(in) = VDD

.print v(out)

vVDD VDD 0  VDD
vVSS VSS 0  0 
VVNW VNW 0  VDD
VVPW VPW 0  0

.tran 100 1000 

.end
```

If I execute this code I get the output voltage around 271m at time = 1000. But if I replace "vin in 0 VDD" with "vin in 0 0" I get v(out) as 250m at time =1000. The inverter model is a standard one and there is no issue there. What could be the problem?

Comment: You are using VDD and VSS as identifiers for both parameters and nodes. I don't know if that will cause problems but is seems dangerous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh sorry the error was the pin configurations. I had given the wrong biases to VNW and VPW which are the substrate bias voltages. Its corrected now.